# Automate git bisect for MSBuild/NUnit/.NET/Windows batch commands in msysgit?

Tags: git, bash, msbuild, nunit, msysgit

I would like to [automate `git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) (instructions also available at [official Linux Kernel Git documenation for `git bisect`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html#_examples)) for building a .NET project with [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), and run unit tests for it with [`nunit-console.exe`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.6.2).  However, these tools were built for use in a Windows development environment, and I'm having various issues with getting them to work in the Bash environment of msysgit, summarized as follows:

1. Bash can't seem to find `MSBuild.exe` nor `nunit-console.exe` (path issue).
2. Both `MSBuild.exe` and `nunit-console.exe` use Windows style commandline option flags, i.e. they begin with a foward slash, e.g. `MSBuild.exe /M`. In Bash the forward slashes cause errors, because a forward slash is what Unix/Linux/*nix systems use to represent directory paths.

This is the `git bisect` command I've been using:

```
$ git bisect start <bad commit> <good commit>
$ git bisect run auto-build-run-tests.sh
```

and these are the contents of `auto-build-run-tests.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html
# http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

# Build solution.
echo "Building..."

MSBuild.exe \
    /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly \
    /maxcpucount \
    /nologo \
    /property:Configuration=Debug \
    /verbosity:quiet \
    "Epic-Project-of-Supreme-Awesome.sln"

# Check exit status.
# (status != 0) ?
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Build failure, status $status."
        exit $status
fi

echo "Build success."

# Run unit tests
nunit-console.exe \
    /noresult \
    /stoponerror \
    "bin/Debug/ArtificialIntelligence.Tests.dll" \
    "bin/Debug/TravelingSalesManSolver.Tests.dll"

status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Test failure, status $status."
        exit $status
fi

echo "Tests passed."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the path problem, I simply used an absolute path in the script. To solve the Windows-style forward-slash commandline-option problem, I escaped the forward-slash with another forward slash (I got that tip from another Stack Overflow answer, I'll link to it when I find it again).

So now the working script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html
# http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

# Build solution.
echo "Building..."

c:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe \
    //consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly \
    //maxcpucount \
    //nologo \
    //property:Configuration=Debug \
    //verbosity:quiet \
    Epic-Project-of-Supreme-Awesome.sln

# Check exit status.
# (status != 0) ?
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Build failure, status $status."
        exit $status
fi

echo "Build success."

# Run unit tests
nunit-console.exe \
    //noresult \
    //stoponerror \
    bin/Debug/ArtificialIntelligence.Tests.dll \
    bin/Debug/TravelingSalesManSolver.Tests.dll

status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Test failure, status $status."
        exit $status
fi

echo "Tests passed."
```

and once again, you run it like this:

```
$ git bisect start <bad commit> <good commit>
$ git bisect run auto-build-run-tests.sh
```

Comment: Just for future readers, many ms tools will recognize when they are in a *nix-like shell and accept - instead of / for arguments. I know that msbuild will (e.g. `-verbosity:quiet`); not sure about nunit.